# How to generate a certificate signing request (CSR) file and a KeyPairs in Azure ADB2C?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-keyvault, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-secrets

I have a usecase to create a KeyPair within Azure ADB2C, and with these Keypair need to generate a “CSR Certificate file” and share to back team.

Where I have gone through couple of references to achieve this scenario but no solution yet.

Is there any proper method to create a “KeyPair” using ADB2C policy-keys option, and using those keys how to generate a CSR certificate file? if there any approach exists?. Also, is there any way that we can generate a CSR file without azure keyvalut within ADB2C portal?

##your valuable suggestions might helps a lot.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

A CSR is just a certificate request. When you [create a certificate request](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/certificates/create-certificate-signing-request), the public and private key pair is generated directly in Key Vault, and then the certificate request with the public key can be downloaded, signed, and merged back into Key Vault so that the certificate is trusted as long as your signing certificate chain terminates in a trusted root for the application verifying the certificate.

If you're looking to automate this process, see our [Azure SDKs for Key Vault certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/client-libraries).

Comment: Hi Heath, I’m currently implementing azure ADB2C for IAM solution, in this implementation process from b2c portal we need to call an authenticated APIs which were hosted on gateway. So, to authenticate the ADB2C request by gateway, first in ADB2C we need to create Client certificate within the B2C portal sources, but not to create a certificate in local machine using tools like powershell. Which I have tried to create but doesn’t work for my usecase. So, can you please suggest if there is a way for “ How B2C can do a client authenticated SSL at the transport layer to the api endpoint Gateway”.

Comment: You can create a certificate in Key Vault or import one (which is supported; if it doesn't work for you, please post more information) and get the public key from key vault, which is the "cer" member if you're using REST APIs. How that is set up in ADB2C I don't know - I couldn't find any specific information about that, but if they have a way to upload the public key, use that. Or is it AD trying to auth to something and needs the private key? Can you link what documentation you're referencing?